# Coin drop animation

Tags: android, animation

I have created a coin dropping animation. Like, I have 10 coins and I will drop them one by one from top to bottom. For dropping effect, I'm using translate animation and it's working fine.

Now, my question is how can I put coins like in the image:

[image: coins]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to help others understand your issue, please post a sample of code or something to demonstrate a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this coins in a relative layout with margin top or bottom to override coin images. margin should be less than or equal to coin image height and also give some left margin to fill effects.